# How can i count and sort a NSMutableArray duplicate values

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I've seen this question:
    [NSMutableArray counting occurances of objects and then re-arange the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276830/nsmutablearray-counting-occurances-of-objects-and-then-re-arange-the-array)

The solution comes very close to what i need.

The solution I'm referring to:

```
NSInteger countedSort(id obj1, id obj2, void *context) {
   NSCountedSet *countedSet = context;
   NSUInteger obj1Count = [countedSet countForObject:obj1];
   NSUInteger obj2Count = [countedSet countForObject:obj2];

   if (obj1Count > obj2Count) return NSOrderedAscending;
   else if (obj1Count < obj2Count) return NSOrderedDescending;
   return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

and:

```
NSMutableArray *array = …;

NSCountedSet *countedSet = [[[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:array]
autorelease];

[array sortUsingFunction:countedSort context:countedSet];
```

The sort returns proper sorted array by count, but i need the count either included or in another array sorted ascending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be to simply query the counted set for the count of any object, to build an array that keep track of the counts:

```
// This after having sorted the array:
NSMutableArray* counts= [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: array.count];
for(id object in array) {
    [counts addObject: @([countedSet countForObject: object]) ];
}
```

Comment: A simple solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This return a sorted array ordered by the most occurring value

```
NSCountedSet *countedSet = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:array];

NSArray *sortedValues = [countedSet.allObjects sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSUInteger n = [countedSet countForObject:obj1];
    NSUInteger m = [countedSet countForObject:obj2];
    return (n <= m)? (n < m)? NSOrderedDescending : NSOrderedSame : NSOrderedAscending;
}];
```